# Tk can't be master of Toplevel

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Classes.py

```
from tkinter import *
BGCL = '#000000'
CANCELCL = '#800000'
CANCELHOVCL = '#400000'
INFOCL = '#000080'
INFOHOVCL = '#000040'
BARCL = '#004000'
STROKECL = '#00c000'
class FantomForm(Tk):
   def __init__(self):
      Tk.__init__(self)
      self.withdraw()
class MainForm(Tk):
   def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self['bg'] = BGCL

        self.overrideredirect(True)
        
        self.bar = Frame(self,bg = BARCL)
        self.bar.place(x = 0 ,y = 0,relwidth = 1,height = 24)
        self.closebtn = Button(self,bg = CANCELCL,fg = BGCL,relief = FLAT,command = self.Exit,bd=0,activebackground = BGCL)
        #print(self.winfo_reqwidth())
        self.closebtn.place(width =24,height = 24,x = self.winfo_reqwidth()-24)
         
        self.bar.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.StartMove)
        self.bar.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.StopMove)
        self.bar.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.OnMotion)
        self.closebtn.bind("<Enter>",self.__closebtne)
        self.closebtn.bind("<Leave>",self.__closebtnl)
   def __closebtne(self,event = None):
      self.closebtn['bg'] = CANCELHOVCL
   def __closebtnl(self,event = None):
      self.closebtn['bg'] = CANCELCL
   def StartMove(self, event = None):
        self.dragx = event.x
        self.dragy = event.y

   def StopMove(self, event = None):
        self.dragx = None
        self.dragy = None

   def OnMotion(self, event = None):
        deltax = event.x - self.dragx
        deltay = event.y - self.dragy
        x = self.winfo_x() + deltax
        y = self.winfo_y() + deltay
        self.geometry("+%s+%s" % (x, y))
   def Exit(self,event = None):
      self.destroy()
class Form(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self,master = None):
        Toplevel.__init__(self,master)
        self['bg'] = BGCL

        self.overrideredirect(True)
        
        self.bar = Frame(self,bg = BARCL)
        self.bar.place(x = 0 ,y = 0,relwidth = 1,height = 24)
        self.closebtn = Button(self,bg = CANCELCL,fg = BGCL,relief = FLAT,command = self.Exit,bd=0,activebackground = BGCL)
        #print(self.winfo_reqwidth())
        self.closebtn.place(width =24,height = 24,x = self.winfo_reqwidth()-24)
         
        self.bar.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.StartMove)
        self.bar.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.StopMove)
        self.bar.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.OnMotion)
        self.closebtn.bind("<Enter>",self.__closebtne)
        self.closebtn.bind("<Leave>",self.__closebtnl)
    def __closebtne(self,event = None):
      self.closebtn['bg'] = CANCELHOVCL
    def __closebtnl(self,event = None):
      self.closebtn['bg'] = CANCELCL
    def StartMove(self, event = None):
        self.dragx = event.x
        self.dragy = event.y

    def StopMove(self, event = None):
        self.dragx = None
        self.dragy = None

    def OnMotion(self, event = None):
        deltax = event.x - self.dragx
        deltay = event.y - self.dragy
        x = self.winfo_x() + deltax
        y = self.winfo_y() + deltay
        self.geometry("+%s+%s" % (x, y))
    def Exit(self,event = None):
      self.destroy()
```

Main.py

```
from Classes import *

Form0 = MainForm()
Form1 = Form(MainForm)
Form0.mainloop()
Form1.mainloop()
```

[image: Error log]

MainForm is class based on Tk
Form is class based on Toplevel

Comment: ```Form1.mainloop()``` it is a ```Toplevel```, why use ```mainloop```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of errors. Take the time to copy, paste, and properly format the error in your question. Also, the solution to stackoverflow saying you have a short description is to improve your description rather than supplying junk text. You can almost certainly reduce the code by more than half and still be able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I have rolled back your post to the one with English text. Please write content only in English.

Answer (score 1):

The master for a widget must be another widget. You're passing a *class*, and a class isn't a widget. You can use an instance of the class, however.

Instead of this:

```
Form0 = MainForm()
Form1 = Form(MainForm)
```

do this:

```
Form0 = MainForm()
Form1 = Form(Form0)
```

Also, you should only call `mainloop` once. You shouldn't call it for every window.